# browser size html css

Tags: iphone, html, css, resize

I have been using the following css code:

```
#MainBox
{   width: 488px;
    height: 181px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 236px; 
    margin-left: -244px; //this being half the width
}
```

To ensure that the items on the page are centred. The problem is, when viewing this on an iphone (and i'm assuming similar on other smartphones) the left hand side of the page is chopped off! Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue and bring everything into fit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're moving the element to the left by 244px with that CSS, and the iphone screen being so small this is causing it to be cut off. Try this:

```
#MainBox{
    width: 488px;
    height: 181px;
    margin: 236px auto 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I should add that this type of CSS isn't a good solution for all screen sizes because even with the above your content will be pushed down 236px which is roughly half the height of the iphone screen. You should look into Responsive Design with media queries

Answer (score 0):

The technique above to center a div is a little obsolete.
Use margin: auto, width to a fixed value (which you already have), and make the parent position:relative.